# Query Error in Oracle to Extract Cell data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to obtain a value from the fields of a column that sometimes vary, with the intention of making the data homogeneous. I get `ORA-00911: invalid character`. I don't know what I might be missing?

| K.C93FECHA_APL | K.93FECHA_APL |
| --- | --- |
| ARONDON | C26cupo : 5000000 |
| BCRUZ | C26cupo : 200000000 |
| BMARIN | C26cupo : 150000000 C26edadretiroforzoso : 70 C26limimite edad : 68 |

Note that the last record not only has the field `C26cupo:`, but also `C26edadretiroforzoso:` and `C26limimite edad:`, and there is a space between the ":"

I should be able to obtain this:

| K.C93FECHA_APL | K.93FECHA_APL |
| --- | --- |
| ARONDON | C26cupo : 5000000 |
| BCRUZ | C26cupo : 200000000 |
| BMARIN | C26cupo : 150000000 |

I have used this code.

```
SELECT 
  K.C93USUARIO, 
  K.C93FECHA_APL, 
  CONCAT('C26cupo:', TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(K.C93VALANTES, INSTR(K.C93VALANTES, 'C26cupo:') + LENGTH('C26cupo:')))) AS C93VALANTES
FROM t93_log K
WHERE K.C93USUARIO IN ('vkmateus918')
  AND K.C93FECHA_APL >= TO_DATE('2022/10/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  AND K.C93FECHA_APL <= TO_DATE('2022/10/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  AND K.C93IDPROCESO IN ('pagaduriabean') 
  AND K.C93TRANSACCION IN ('UPDATE')
  AND K.C93VALANTES NOT LIKE '%CONSOLIDADORA%'
  AND K.C93VALANTES NOT LIKE '%C26OPCIONCAMPO2 :%'
  AND K.C93CAMPO LIKE '%C26CUPO%'
  AND INSTR(K.C93VALANTES, 'C26cupo:') > 0
```

But I get the mentioned error

Comment: Your sample output and your query do not match as the query has 3 columns but the sample output only has 2 columns that are both named identically. Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do? See line #7.

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'ARONDON', 'C26cupo : 5000000' from dual union all
  3     select 'BCRUZ'  , 'C26cupo : 200000000' from dual union all
  4     select 'BMARIN' , 'C26cupo : 150000000 C26edadretiroforzoso : 70 C26limimite edad : 68' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col1,
  7    regexp_substr(col2, 'C26cupo : \d+') result
  8  from test;

COL1    RESULT
------- ------------------------------
ARONDON C26cupo : 5000000
BCRUZ   C26cupo : 200000000
BMARIN  C26cupo : 150000000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know/have/want regexp (or it is just too slow), you can try to do it [using SubStr() and InStr()](https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-substr/) functions:

```sql
WITH        -- Sample data
    tbl (A_NAME, FLDS) as
        (   select 'ARONDON', 'C26cupo : 5000000' from dual union all
            select 'BCRUZ'  , 'C26cupo : 200000000' from dual union all
            select 'BMARIN' , 'C26cupo : 150000000 C26edadretiroforzoso : 70 C26limimite edad : 68' from dual
        )
--
--  Main SQL
Select  A_NAME,
  -- get substring starting from position 1 with length defined by position of the first blank ' ' after the position of ' : ' plus 3 characters
        SubStr( FLDS || ' ', 1, InStr(FLDS || ' ', ' ', InStr(FLDS || ' ', ' : ', 1, 1) + 3) - 1 ) "FLD"  
  -- the -1 at the end excludes mentioned blank space from the result (You can use RTRIM() instead)
From    tbl
--
--  R e s u l t :
A_NAME  FLD                   
------- ----------------------
ARONDON C26cupo : 5000000     
BCRUZ   C26cupo : 200000000   
BMARIN  C26cupo : 150000000
```

Note: there is a blank space char added to FLDS column in the code to fetch rows that doesn't have any blanks after the ' : ' part of the string...